# Gnuplot: arrow on logscale plot

Tags: gnuplot

Take the following MWE for instance:

```
set logscale xy
set arrow 1 from 1, graph 0 to 1, graph 1
set arrow 2 from graph 0,1e+02 to graph 1,1e+02
p [x=0.001:100] (10**x)**(.111111) t ''
```

Arrow 1 will show up just fine but arrow 2 does not.  I've also tried

```
set arrow 2 from graph 0,100 to graph 1,100
```

and, in case there was some log scaling issue,

```
set arrow 2 from graph 0,2 to graph 1,2.
```

Arrow 2 is still MIA.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The coordinate type (here: `graph`) which you specified for the x-coordinate of an arrow point is also used for y-coordinate:

- `1, graph 0` is equivalent to `first 1, graph 0`
- but `graph 0,100` is equivalent to `graph 0, graph 100`.

That means, that your second arrow is completely outside of the plotting window.

```
set logscale xy
set arrow 1 from 1, graph 0 to 1, graph 1
set arrow 2 from graph 0, first 1e+02 to graph 1, first 1e+02
p [x=0.001:100] (10**x)**(.111111) t ''
```

[image]